# Time calculations and counts with mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my database layout:

- ID (int - unique primary key
- user (int) - foreign key for users I search by their `name` colum
- starttime (timestamp) - session start time
- endtime (timestamp) - session end time
- idletime (int) - idle time in minutes

For example I want to know how many minutes a specific player was online.

The following query works fine. I get about 3443 minutes.

```
SELECT user, 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,starttime,endtime)-idletime) 
FROM gc_sessions 
WHERE user = 139
```

But if I want to do this with joins I get 8 by using the following query.

```
 SELECT name, 
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,starttime,endtime)-idletime) 
 FROM gc_sessions 
 JOIN gc_users ON gc_user.id = gc_sessions.id
WHERE name LIKE "variell"
```

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: `gc_users`.`id` [determine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) `gc_users`.`user` ?

Comment: @Karsten Detmold - i modified my answer. please try new query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following query and tell me the result

```
SELECT `name`, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`starttime`,`endtime`)-`idletime`) 
    FROM `gc_sessions` inner JOIN `gc_users` ON 
    `gc_sessions`.`user` =`gc_users`.`id` WHERE gc_users.`name` LIKE "variell"
```

Comment: @KarstenDetmold - can you please provide table creation query of both tables ?

Comment: @KarstenDetmold - i modified my above query. please run that too

Answer (score 0):

Try `group by`:

```
 SELECT name, 
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,starttime,endtime)-idletime) 
 FROM gc_sessions 
 JOIN gc_users ON gc_user.id = gc_sessions.userid
WHERE name LIKE "variell"
GROUP BY name
;
```

Not sure about your entire table schema, but the fist thing to notice was that you were having `on gc_users.id = gc_seeions.id`. It has to be both userids. According to the following demo, your query works even without `group by`. The next possible issue could be with **LIKE** operator. If you want exact name `Variell` then it shouldn't be `like` but `=`. If you want to use `Like` it simply says that you may also trying to get any name that contains this string.. however without knowing table schema ans sample data, it's hard to commit the exact reason.

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a17b45/6)

Results:

```
|    NAME | TOTALTIME |
-----------------------
| variell |       308 |
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO WITH wildcards](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a17b45/7)

Query:

```
SELECT gu.name, 
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,gs.starttime,
                          gs.endtime)-gs.idletime) AS TotalTime
 FROM gc_sessions gs 
 JOIN gc_users gu ON gs.userid = gu.id
WHERE gu.name LIKE "%variell%"
GROUP BY gu.name
;

|     NAME | TOTALTIME |
------------------------
| dvariell |       286 |
|  variell |       308 |
```

Comment: @KarstenDetmold give this one a try and comment please.